# libgdx:load skin in AssetManages

Tags: libgdx

I'm using LibGDX and I want to load skin in AssetManager.

Previously I use this code for loading skin , but now I want to load skin (with atlas images) in my assets class using assetmanager. Here is my old code:

```
    gameUIAtlas = new TextureAtlas("images/game_ui.pack");
    gameUISkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/game_ui.json"), gameUIAtlas);
```

How I try to load skin, but I don't know how to assign atlas(images) to this skin

```
    assetManager.load(""ui/game_ui.json", Skin.class);
    Skin skin = assetManager.get("ui/game_ui.json");
```

I receive this error : `Asset not loaded: ui/game_ui.json`

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load(..)` doesn't actually load the asset, it just queues it for loading.
You need to call `finishLoading()` first or consecutively call `update()`:

```
while(!assetManager.update())
    Gdx.app.log("loading", (assetManager.getProgress() * 100) + " %");
```

See the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#loading-assets) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes I call this two methods. I don't know how to assign images that are stored in `images/game_ui.pack` with `ui/game_ui.json` file. In assetmanager I call only json file.How can I tell that images used in .json file are in game_ui.pack ?

Comment: You have two possibilities: Use `assetManager.load("ui/game_ui.json", Skin.class, new SkinParameter("images/game_ui.pack"));` or rename `images/game_ui.pack` to `ui/game_ui.atlas`.